# Batch - How can I copy files with filetype A from a subfolder A of Path A to subfolder A of Path B?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy all file types that are in different paths with same subfolder names.

Example,

I want to copy from:

```
C:\PathA\FolderA\file1.filetype1
C:\PathA\FolderB\file2.filetype1
C:\PathA\FolderC\file3.filetype1
.
.
.
```

into:

```
C:\PathB\FolderA\file1.filetype1
C:\PathB\FolderB\file2.filetype1
C:\PathB\FolderC\file3.filetype1
.
.
.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy files with specific type only, you can do this:

```
xcopy (SourceDirectory)\.filetype .\(DestinationDirectory) /S /Y
```

**/S**: copies directories and subdirectories (excluding empty), you need to specify this argument to work with subdirectories

**/Y**: automatically confirm to overwrite existing files in destination directory

You can specify **/E** instead of **/S** to copy empty directories.